# Method Overloading Techinques

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a method overload that goes as follows:

```
public class Odddetector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = countOdd(new int [] {5, 7, 3, 9, 0});
        System.out.println(count);
        count = countOdd(new int [] {2, 6, 4, 8, 1});
        System.out.println(count);
        count = countOdd(5, 7, 10);
        System.out.println(count);
        count = countOdd(8, 2, 7);
        System.out.println(count);
        count = countOdd(new int[][] {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}});//extra point only
        System.out.println(count);
        count = countOdd(new int[][] {{6, 2}, {3, 4, 0}});//extra point only
        System.out.println(count);
    }
public static int countOdd(int[] a){
      int count=0;
      for (int i: a) count = (i %2 != 0)?++count:count;
      return count;
      // Do Something;
}
public static int countOdd(int[][] a){
     // Do Something;
     int count=0;
     for (int b = 0; b< a.length; b++){
            //System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a[b])); not a necessary line.
            count += countOdd(a[b]);
        }
      return count;
}
// more method overloading
```

My question is there a way to condense the solution to have one method that takes into account N-Dimensional Arrays. The code runs fine like this however, I would like to know what Java techniques can help account for the increase in dimensions. I would like to add some details and that is that the first method is the base method, and all the other methods call that first int[] a. The new section I added is the full code I am currently in developing this code which my professor gave as a challenge. I currently have the Data Structures by Lang, and I can accept hints. I prefer hints actually because I would like to learn to code this.

Comment: I think it would depend on what `// Do Something;` actually does.

Comment: Ok sure I'll add it

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it builds up from that first method, and only looks at a 1D array, and counts the odd numbers, my problem is I want to find a way to condense the constant calling of the method.

Comment: I tried to come up with a recursive method but couldn't get the varargs method to overload, so I had to call it something different. Now it's lunchtime... But you can check it out here: https://ideone.com/5uf77A Maybe it will set you in the right direction.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, your attempt should be posted as an answer.  Minor improvement: it could make sense to add a class check `if (a[0] instanceof Number)`, then cast `i` to `Number` and use its `Number::intValue` method when checking for oddity instead of casting to `int`.

Comment: I agree actually it's very unique, and interesting I will accept it if it is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the parameter is amulti dimensional array, you can recursively call the function that digs down until you end up with a 1d array of numbers. The logic is:

```
if a is a multi-dimensional array
    for each array in a
        call recursively
else
    count odd numbers in a
```

I have 2 functions. One that takes a variable number of args, and a recursive one. The first just calls the second with the var args as an array. The varargs function needs a bit of work if you want to allow mixed parameters (eg: `countOdd(new int [] {1,2,3}, 4, 5);`)

```
// The var args version. You call this. It then calls the recursive
// version.
public static <T> int countOdd(T... arguments)
{
   return countOddRec(arguments);
}

// Recursive version
private static <T> int countOddRec(T[] a)
{
    if (a == null || a.length == 0) return 0;
    
    int count=0;

    // Is it an array of Numbers?
    if (a[0] instanceof Number) {
        for (T i: a) {
            // Simplified the counting code a bit. Any # mod 2 is either 0 or 1
            count += ((Number)i).intValue() % 2;
        }
    }
    // Is it an multi-dimensional? Call recursively for each sub-array.
    else {
        for (T sub : a) {
            count += countOddRec((T[])sub);
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this will not work for primitive data types (ex: `int`, etc). Instead, use non-primitive types (ex: `Integer`, etc).

Comment: Will not work for primitives though

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I doubted it, and checked. It doesn't work - cast to `T[]` (near method end) fails for nested array, because parameter `T` can only be an `Object` and after erasure there will be pure cast to `Object[]`, but `int[]` is **not** instanceof `Object[]`

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky Yes, I am agreeing with you that it won't work with primitive types. Converting everything to `Integer` does work: https://ideone.com/VJh8Ox

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess there are some very interesting problems around, all coupled together. Namely

1. How to generify array processing and method declaration for
   arbitrary depth (this is your initial question)?
2. How to deep traverse array with unknown depth?
3. How to inject some useful payload
   into array traversal (in your case - count odd numbers)
   independently of traversal itself?
4. Is it possible to generify approach for primitive and object arrays, and how?

I have a good suggestion for points 3: instead of hardcoding payload in the method itself we can produce `IntStream` (or generic `Stream` for `Object` version) which can be processed separately.

On points 1 and 4 my guess it's probably not possible or at least not elegant. `java.lang.reflect.Array` doesn't show any wonder in this and my assumption is - if JDK couldn't do this, I cannot neither. So, the best option is probably to allow general signature with `Object` accompanied with couple of frequently used overloads, up to depth 3. Of course, this implies danger of `ClassCastExceptions` at runtime.

So, final result with implementation of point 2 may look like this

```
public class FlattenArray {
  public static IntStream flatten(int n) {
    return IntStream.of(n);
  }
  public static IntStream flatten(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array);
  }
  public static IntStream flatten(int[][] array) {
    return flatten((Object) array);
  }
  public static IntStream flatten(Object array) {
    Class<?> aClass = array.getClass();
    if (!aClass.isArray())
      return IntStream.of(((Number) array).intValue());
    else {
      Class<?> componentType = aClass.getComponentType();
      if (componentType.isPrimitive())
        return IntStream.of((int[]) array);
      else
        return Arrays.stream((Object[]) array).flatMapToInt(FlattenArray::flatten);
    }
  }
}
```

And use this like

```
long count = FlattenArray.flatten(2, 3, 5, 7).filter(i -> i & 1 != 0).count();
```